# Excel Line breaks/returns

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2012

When I “copy with header” of the data on SQL Server and paste it onto Excel there is like a return line or breaks. Is there a way for me to remove the breaks or the returns?

I tried using select all and copy with header onto excel and the data is not the same because of the line/return breaks.

Also tried saving as .csv and also tried saving as .xls and the data is still not the same

[This is what it looks like when I tried to copy and paste it with headers or saving as .csv and .xls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvKDj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating the **Retain CR/LF on copy or save** setting in SSMS.  On the menu, go to **Tools** then **Options**.  From here select **Query Results**, then **SQL Server**, and **Results to Grid** below there.  After you update the **Retain CR/LF on copy or save** option a new session will need to be created for this to become effective, which can be done by just opening a new query window in SSMS.